# How to allow network flow between two private instances which are attached to different elb's?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I had created an VPC with public and private subnets. For public subnets I attached internet gateway for private subnets nat gateway, From here my plan is to launch all my instances in private subnet and connect them with outside world using elb, for that I launched my tomcat server in private subnet and attached to elb which is in public subnet and I launched mongodb in private subnet and public subnet elb is attached to it. Now when I call an API from tomcat server it should fetch the data from db, It's happening when I allow 27017 (port of mongodb) from anywhere in elb sg, Here is where I'm facing issue I don't want to allow the port from every where only tomcat servers should talk with the mongodb through elb how to configure security groups of elb to allow traffic from only tomcat servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

Since your tomcat servers are in a private subnet and it is trying to reach the mongodb ELB in a public subnet, the tomcast servers' outbound traffic must be routed through a NAT gateway (**Not the ELB**).

So instead of setting the security group to allow 27017 port from 0.0.0.0/0, you can allow 27017 port from the NAT gateway IP.

You will first need to check whether you are using the old-style NAT gateway instance or the new VPC NAT gateway solution in order to obtain the required IP address.

**Suggestions:**

First, you do not want to expose the traffic between your instance and your database to public internet. Use a private load balancer instead.

Second, you do not need an ELB for the mongodb cluster (I assume you have a cluster). The purpose of a Mongodb cluster is for high availability. [Write always go to the primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-primary/), and [it is a bad practice to use secondaries to increase performance for read requests](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#counter-indications).

You should setup mongos to accept connections and let it take care of the routing for you. In this case your tomcast servers can connect to the private mongos endpoint directly without exposing traffic to the internet.

If you are not using mongodb cluster (In this case I don't understand why you used a load balancer in the first place) then it is even simpler, just connect using the mongodb server private IP.

Comment: Happy to help. Please mark this as accepted answer if it solved your issue. Anyway just an unrelated architecture suggestion - do not route the connection between your application and your database through public network.

Comment: do not route the connection between your application and your database through public network ? what's the best architecture design you can suggest. Please let me know

Comment: I added some suggestions in my solution, I was going to say use a private load balancer instead but it suddenly came to me that you should not be using a load balancer at all for mongodb cluster.

Comment: Got it, why I am using internet facing load balancer is still I didn't configure VPN to my network, If I want to connect to mongo db from my home using Robo 3T I can't connect if my db is in internal load balancer or if I create dns name directly in route 53 for private IP, So once I have VPN as you said I don't need LB also. I think this is what you are conveying me? please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks for your suggestion it's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a security group dedicated to this communication between your servers and the db and attach this security group to both of them.

I do not recommend using a NAT for public application, because this NAT instance may not be able to support peaks of load.

Comment: Hence all my servers are in private subnet, I added private ip's of those instance in sg of elb's, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to set a security group in common of your instances? For example if you have an ec2 instance "my-instance1" and a rds instance "my-rds-instance", attach a security group "sg-gateway" to both of them to allow communication between these two instances.